# How to use method to output a random string from array?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

How can I fix the code so my method compiles correctly to output a random string from the array I created into the main method?

```
class Main
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {   
   randomWord(); 
   System.out.println (random);
  }

  static String[] randomWord()
  {
    String[] randomWords = {"dog", "cat", "monkey"}
    String random = randomWords[(int)(Math.random() * randomWords.length)];
    return random; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Return a `String` instead of a `String[]`

Comment: ...and actually assign the return value somewhere, instead of letting it vanish into thin air.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to not understand how to use methods with return values. This method:

```
  static String[] randomWord()
  {
    String[] randomWords = {"dog", "cat", "monkey"}
    String random = randomWords[(int)(Math.random() * randomWords.length)];
    return random; 
  }
```

Should really return a `String` instead of `String[]`, because what you are returning, `random`, is a string. So change it to:

```
  static String randomWord()
  // ...
```

To use this method, you don't just call it like this:

```
randomWord()
```

This will discard the return value. To get the return value, you can create a variable:

```
String random = randomWord();
```

Now you can print it:

```
System.out.println(random);
```

You can write the two lines in one line as well:

```
System.out.println(randomWord());
```

Answer (score 1):

The random index range have to be 0 <= yourArraySize

```
static String randomWord()
    {
        String[] randomWords = {"dog", "cat", "monkey"};
        return randomWords[ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, randomWords.length + 1)];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs 2 little modifications, and I'll explain each change and why.

Here is a working version after applying changes:

```
public class Main {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println(randomWord()); //randomWord() returns the random string which is directly printed
     }

     static String randomWord() {
     String[] randomWords = {"dog", "cat", "monkey"};
     return randomWords[(int) (Math.random() * randomWords.length)];
     }
}
```

Tweaks made:

1- You are printing out variable 'random' which cannot be accessed in your main method since its a local variable to method 'randomWord()'

*Code Modified* to print the returned value of the 'randomWord()' method itself

```
 System.out.println(randomWord());
```

2- 'randomWord()' is defined to return a String array, But in actuality you are returning a string variable 'random'

*Code Modified* to return a String in the definition

```
 static String randomWord()
```